# how to prevent firefox from opening a downloaded file in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a selenium test to click on a button and download a file. It is downloading the file, but the browser always opens it in the middle of the execution, opening a new tab on firefox and breaking my test.

I tried to set the preferences in code, but it's not working.

```
firefox_options = Options()

firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/tmp")
firefox_options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,text/csv")

driver = Firefox(options=firefox_options)
```

Is there any additional preference to prevent this behavior?

Comment: If you're doing browser automation in 2023, probably give playwright a try instead of selenium. No web driver, and you get to use chromium, firefox, _and_ webkit on all operating systems (including Windows)